# Best installer to integrate with TFS2010+MSBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild, installation

So it looks like Microsoft's installer projects don't build with MSBuild. Which is what we are using with TFS2010.

This means that that my dream of check in the code, continuous integration build-> installer are currently doused.

I know people out there are doing it, so they must be using some other installer tech. I noticed VS2010 now comes with installsheild lite. I just want to do some basic stuff with the installer, run on startup kind of stuff. Should I pursue installsheild lite, look at WiX or is there something better.

My main criteria is that it integrates seamlessly into the solutions so that we can have TFS2010 doing our continuous integration and nightly builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WIX all the way.  We use it to package close to a hundred different MSIs for our corporate deployments.

http://wix.codeplex.com/

Package specification is via XML files.  There's a bit of a learning curve, but it is very powerful... and MSBuild can build them.

Comment: damnit, no matter how many times I press, I can only vote once!

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that InstallShield is going to be the out of the box recommendation going forward.  Wix is cool and powerful, but the day 1 experience is...err... less than pleasing.